# MongoDB find query params

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, express

I have a mongo query on a collection. It looks like this:

```
common.db.collection('vb.vbStats').find({uid:uid, "vbs.vbNID":vbNID}, {"vbs.$":1}).toArray(function(err, result) {....}
```

vb.vbstats is my collection. vbs is a field of the collection that is an array of arrays of ducoments. My question is what does `{"vbs.$":1}` in the query.

Comment: That is the [project param](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/glossary/#term-projection) basically limiting what is returned from the docs. The vbs.$ appears to limit the returned array to the first item [$projection](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/projection/positional/#proj._S_) but I'm not too familiar with its usage.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`{"vbs.$":1}` is a query operation that uses the positional $ operator to limit the contents of the array `vbs` from the query results to contain only the first element matching the query document.

So in you example, the projection `{"vbs.$": 1}` returns only the first element in the array `vbs` which has `vbNID = vbNID`. Refer to the [docs](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/projection/positional/#proj._S_) for more details